# Match words in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
dictionary = {u'12.75': u' over ', u'2214.23': u' content ', u'2225.86': u' voor ', u'7.17': u' vraag ', u'11.01': u' bedrijf ', u'2228.27': u' wordt ', u'12.0': u' ik ', u'12.6': u' meer ', u'2223.29': u' ik ', u'6.9': u' paar ', u'17.22': u' binnen ', u'2216.86': u' solide ', u'23.67': u' ja ', u'12.09': u' dan ', u'2212.9': u' jij ', u'21.59': u' ja ', u'20.64': u' opleiding ', u'14.46': u' onderzoek ', u'0.54': u' nou ', u'2224.31': u' genoeg ', u'2223.98': u' ik ', u'2227.99': u' voor ', u'2225.03': u' dat ', u'3.18': u' heel ', u'2216.59': u' lukte ', u'2215.93': u' verder ', u'17.37': u' het ', u'2213.04': u' jij ', u'2226.13': u' is ', u'1.76': u' was ', u'11.66': u' maar ', u'2221.22': u' denk ', u'3.02': u' ben ', u'2216.42': u' dat ', u'12.43': u' iets ', u'11.84': u' ga ', u'2215.82': u' dat ', u'4.68': u' zelf ', u'2220.65': u' dat ', u'2.45': u' lekker ', u'2219.08': u' gekapt ', u'2215.73': u' om ', u'11.77': u' daar ', u'13.83': u' ik ', u'18.03': u' founder ', u'22.91': u' een ', u'14.91': u' ben ', u'5.27': u' koken ', u'2226.53': u' je ', u'2218.8': u' mijn ', u'22.19': u' ik ', u'2214.64': u' wordt ', u'14.18': u' van ', u'2226.59': u' hebt ', u'3.83': u' ik ', u'2224.61': u' ik ', u'20.25': u' zelf ', u'2227.1': u' alles ', u'16.89': u' functie ', u'2216.27': u' gaan ', u'9.81': u' eerst ', u'4.46': u' speel ', u'2221.49': u' was ', u'22.64': u' ik ', u'2224.73': u' zeg ', u'2.68': u' mee ', u'0.99': u' hele ', u'0.8': u' mijn ', u'19.2': u' klopt ', u'2.88': u' en ', u'3.59': u' pak ', u'10.08': u' over ', u'14.37': u' het ', u'13.9': u' zelf ', u'2226.38': u' en ', u'21.09': u' gedaan ', u'22.76': u' zo ', u'2215.2': u' ook ', u'2220.91': u' dat ', u'2213.5': u' alles ', u'2220.12': u' dus ', u'2221.1': u' is ', u'2221.4': u' ik ', u'17.43': u' bedrijf ', u'2220.4': u' wat ', u'2221.62': u' moeilijk ', u'2228.15': u' mij ', u'4.26': u' ik ', u'2224.13': u' weet ', u'13.67': u' wat ', u'22.49': u' of ', u'11.34': u' zelf ', u'2215.37': u' geprobeerd ', u'7.72': u' is ', u'1.23': u' jeugd ', u'2216.18': u' te '}
```

Now I rank this dictionary and call it sorted_dictionary:

```
sorted_dictionary = [(u'0.54', u' nou '), (u'0.8', u' mijn '), (u'0.99', u' hele '), (u'1.23', u' jeugd '), (u'1.76', u' was '), (u'10.08', u' over '), (u'11.01', u' bedrijf '), (u'11.34', u' zelf '), (u'11.66', u' maar '), (u'11.77', u' daar '), (u'11.84', u' ga '), (u'12.0', u' ik '), (u'12.09', u' dan '), (u'12.43', u' iets '), (u'12.6', u' meer '), (u'12.75', u' over '), (u'13.67', u' wat '), (u'13.83', u' ik '), (u'13.9', u' zelf '), (u'14.18', u' van '), (u'14.37', u' het '), (u'14.46', u' onderzoek '), (u'14.91', u' ben '), (u'16.89', u' functie '), (u'17.22', u' binnen '), (u'17.37', u' het '), (u'17.43', u' bedrijf '), (u'18.03', u' founder '), (u'19.2', u' klopt '), (u'2.45', u' lekker '), (u'2.68', u' mee '), (u'2.88', u' en '), (u'20.25', u' zelf '), (u'20.64', u' opleiding '), (u'21.09', u' gedaan '), (u'21.59', u' ja '), (u'22.19', u' ik '), (u'22.49', u' of '), (u'22.64', u' ik '), (u'22.76', u' zo '), (u'22.91', u' een '), (u'2212.9', u' jij '), (u'2213.04', u' jij '), (u'2213.5', u' alles '), (u'2214.23', u' content '), (u'2214.64', u' wordt '), (u'2215.2', u' ook '), (u'2215.37', u' geprobeerd '), (u'2215.73', u' om '), (u'2215.82', u' dat '), (u'2215.93', u' verder '), (u'2216.18', u' te '), (u'2216.27', u' gaan '), (u'2216.42', u' dat '), (u'2216.59', u' lukte '), (u'2216.86', u' solide '), (u'2218.8', u' mijn '), (u'2219.08', u' gekapt '), (u'2220.12', u' dus '), (u'2220.4', u' wat '), (u'2220.65', u' dat '), (u'2220.91', u' dat '), (u'2221.1', u' is '), (u'2221.22', u' denk '), (u'2221.4', u' ik '), (u'2221.49', u' was '), (u'2221.62', u' moeilijk '), (u'2223.29', u' ik '), (u'2223.98', u' ik '), (u'2224.13', u' weet '), (u'2224.31', u' genoeg '), (u'2224.61', u' ik '), (u'2224.73', u' zeg '), (u'2225.03', u' dat '), (u'2225.86', u' voor '), (u'2226.13', u' is '), (u'2226.38', u' en '), (u'2226.53', u' je '), (u'2226.59', u' hebt '), (u'2227.1', u' alles '), (u'2227.99', u' voor '), (u'2228.15', u' mij '), (u'2228.27', u' wordt '), (u'23.67', u' ja '), (u'3.02', u' ben '), (u'3.18', u' heel '), (u'3.59', u' pak '), (u'3.83', u' ik '), (u'4.26', u' ik '), (u'4.46', u' speel '), (u'4.68', u' zelf '), (u'5.27', u' koken '), (u'6.9', u' paar '), (u'7.17', u' vraag '), (u'7.72', u' is '), (u'9.81', u' eerst ')]
```

What I want to do now is to loop through the new dictionary to see if trigger words are there. However if I take a word which is obviously there in the dictionary (fe 'now') and I do this:

```
hit = 'nou'

for element in sorted_dictionary:
    element_final = element[1].encode('ascii','ignore')
    print element_final
    if element_final == hit:
        print "succes"
```

I do not get any hits ... Strange cause they are both:

```
<type 'str'>
```

Any thoughts on what goes wrong here?
Thank you!

Comment: the second one is not the dictionary it is a list of tuples

Answer (score 2):

You have leading/trailing spaces around "trigger words" within your list of tuples. Use the following:

```
sorted_dictionary = [(u'0.54', u' nou '), (u'0.8', u' mijn '), (u'0.99', u' hele '), (u'1.23', u' jeugd '), (u'1.76', u' was '), (u'10.08', u' over '), (u'11.01', u' bedrijf '), (u'11.34', u' zelf '), (u'11.66', u' maar '), (u'11.77', u' daar '), (u'11.84', u' ga '), (u'12.0', u' ik '), (u'12.09', u' dan '), (u'12.43', u' iets '), (u'12.6', u' meer '), (u'12.75', u' over '), (u'13.67', u' wat '), (u'13.83', u' ik '), (u'13.9', u' zelf '), (u'14.18', u' van '), (u'14.37', u' het '), (u'14.46', u' onderzoek '), (u'14.91', u' ben '), (u'16.89', u' functie '), (u'17.22', u' binnen '), (u'17.37', u' het '), (u'17.43', u' bedrijf '), (u'18.03', u' founder '), (u'19.2', u' klopt '), (u'2.45', u' lekker '), (u'2.68', u' mee '), (u'2.88', u' en '), (u'20.25', u' zelf '), (u'20.64', u' opleiding '), (u'21.09', u' gedaan '), (u'21.59', u' ja '), (u'22.19', u' ik '), (u'22.49', u' of '), (u'22.64', u' ik '), (u'22.76', u' zo '), (u'22.91', u' een '), (u'2212.9', u' jij '), (u'2213.04', u' jij '), (u'2213.5', u' alles '), (u'2214.23', u' content '), (u'2214.64', u' wordt '), (u'2215.2', u' ook '), (u'2215.37', u' geprobeerd '), (u'2215.73', u' om '), (u'2215.82', u' dat '), (u'2215.93', u' verder '), (u'2216.18', u' te '), (u'2216.27', u' gaan '), (u'2216.42', u' dat '), (u'2216.59', u' lukte '), (u'2216.86', u' solide '), (u'2218.8', u' mijn '), (u'2219.08', u' gekapt '), (u'2220.12', u' dus '), (u'2220.4', u' wat '), (u'2220.65', u' dat '), (u'2220.91', u' dat '), (u'2221.1', u' is '), (u'2221.22', u' denk '), (u'2221.4', u' ik '), (u'2221.49', u' was '), (u'2221.62', u' moeilijk '), (u'2223.29', u' ik '), (u'2223.98', u' ik '), (u'2224.13', u' weet '), (u'2224.31', u' genoeg '), (u'2224.61', u' ik '), (u'2224.73', u' zeg '), (u'2225.03', u' dat '), (u'2225.86', u' voor '), (u'2226.13', u' is '), (u'2226.38', u' en '), (u'2226.53', u' je '), (u'2226.59', u' hebt '), (u'2227.1', u' alles '), (u'2227.99', u' voor '), (u'2228.15', u' mij '), (u'2228.27', u' wordt '), (u'23.67', u' ja '), (u'3.02', u' ben '), (u'3.18', u' heel '), (u'3.59', u' pak '), (u'3.83', u' ik '), (u'4.26', u' ik '), (u'4.46', u' speel '), (u'4.68', u' zelf '), (u'5.27', u' koken '), (u'6.9', u' paar '), (u'7.17', u' vraag '), (u'7.72', u' is '), (u'9.81', u' eerst ')]
hit = 'nou'

for element in sorted_dictionary:
    element_final = element[1].strip()
    if element_final == hit:
        print(element, "succes")
```

The output:

```
('0.54', ' nou ') succes
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if word is in dict values another way:

```
if hit in dict(sorted_dictionary).values()
    print("success")
```

There's also `collections.OrderedDict` class which enables you to create sorted dict from sorted list of 2-value tuples.

Comment: correct your code it has some syntax error
if hit == dict(sorted_dictionary).values()):
    print("success")

Comment: Sorry, fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You need to `strip()` the whitespace around values.

```
for key, value in sorted_dictionary:
    if value.strip() == hit:
        print("success")
```

By the way, better way would be:

```
if hit in [v.strip() for v in dictionary.values()]:
    print("success")
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
    if element_final in hit:

I had this issue before and it worked for me.